# Can you help me fix a 405 error with Django form submission?

Tags: django, django-3.0

I'm having an issue when submitting a form within a class-based view. I'm using the FormMixin in a detail view, and when I submit the form I get a 405 error. I've tried chopping and changing the code in views, but nothing seems to be working.

**Models**

```
class Bid(models.Model):
 author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 tender = models.ForeignKey(Tender, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
 title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 specification = models.TextField()
 timeline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
 price = models.IntegerField()

 def __str__(self):
    return self.title

 def get_absolute_url(self):
      return reverse('bid-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

**Views**

```
class TenderDetailView(FormMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
  model = Tender
  template_name = 'it_me/tender_detail.html'
  form_class = BidForm

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('tender-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.id})

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(TenderDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['form'] = BidForm(initial={'post': self.object})
    return context

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    form = self.get_form()
    if form.is_valid():
        return self.form_valid(form)
    else:
        return self.form_invalid(form)

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.save()
    return super(TenderDetailView, self).form_valid(form)
```

**forms**

```
class BidForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Bid
        fields = ('title', 'specification', 'timeline', 'price')
```

**Templates**

```
 <div class="content-section">
  <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        {{ form|crispy }}
    </fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit"> Post Bid </button>
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>

    {% for bid in tender.bids.all %}
        <div class=" col-md-12 comment">
            <div class="date">{{ bid.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }}</div>
            <strong>{{ bid.author }}</strong>
        </div>
    {% empty %}
        <p>No Bids Yet </p>
    {% endfor %}
```

**urls**

```
path('tender/<int:pk>/', TenderDetailView.as_view(), name='tender-detail')
```

Would really appreciate any help cause I am stumped.

Comment: Did you try to use `UpdateView` instead of `DetailView`? As far as I know, DetailView not supports post requests.

Comment: That's worked a charm, thank you so much. One other thing though, I'm trying to get the details of the submitted form to display in that detail view. Any chance you could help again?

Comment: Once you saved your instance in UpdateView, you are free to show details in DetailView vith instance properties that will retrieved from database. You have passed pk in the url, so you can render instance details in DetailView. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview use `object` name as described in documentation. I will also create an answer to help others.

Answer (score 0):

`DetailView` has no support for post requests. It is aimed to show instance details. As you can see in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview), the view supports only get method. To update your instance, you can use `UpdateView`. [UpdateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView) is the generic view to handle update operation. You can also use these documentation pages for basic practices such as showing the instance details in `DetailView`.